# f# exception raised out of order in a loop

Tags: f#

Is there a reason why the exception is displayed before the function has even started in the following?

```
let listCharacters (text:string) =
    let stripv3 =  text.Split([|' '|], System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) |> System.String.Concat      

    for i in 0..2..stripv3.Length do
            let char = stripv3.Chars(i)
            if char <> ' ' then
                printfn "%c" char  

listCharacters "honey badger is a badass"
```

Produces the following output:-

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
h
n
y
a
g
r
s
b
d
s
```

Interestingly if I add a `try..with` any operations within the with occurs in order, any ideas why this is?

Comment: Output where? FSI output off your snippet in VS2013/F#3.1 looks completely in order to me, i.e. exception after the character lines.

Comment: FSI in VS2015, admittedly I've only just started looking into f# so I'm pretty sure my expectations are out but I'd like to understand why the exception isn't the last line of the output.

Comment: Tried it in VS2015 Enterprise - still the output is as expected (FSI ver 14.0.23020.0).

Comment: Like @GeneBelitski I can reproduce that behaviour in neither Visual Studio  Professional 2015 nor in FSI from the command-line.

Comment: Sorry just got what you said, I can now confirm that the output is exactly as I expect in FSI.exe, it just looks odd in VS F# interactive view.  It is also absolutely fine when run.  Thanks for your help Gene.

Comment: @PaulHodgson: NP, it was a blessing in disguise as looking at it allowed me to spot a probable [bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/734) in FSI v14.

Comment: If you have resolved your problem, it could help other people if you could document your resolution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To summarise the comments above the problem is specific to the IDE and not to the language.

In this instance the issue was only seen in the Visual Studio F# Interactive view.

When executed fully or run via Visual Studio FSI.exe the exception was the last item to be output.